# Can AWS API Gateway handle port 9443

Tags: amazon-web-services, port, aws-api-gateway

I had an old endpoint that was allowed for port 9443.
Now the old server is being deprecated and I have mapped in DNS CName to point to AWS API gateway.

There are many clients who use this endpoint can AWS API Gateway handle this port?
If yes how can I handle this??

Edit: My old endpoint is like this
https://domain:9443/blah.

Its timing out for me

Answer (score 1):

> API Gateway supports the following endpoint ports: 80, 443 and 1024-65535.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/setup-http-integrations.html

Comment: But it's not very clear any steps would be helpful.
It's timing out for me.

Comment: Are you sure your Security Group has opened that port from your IP address @Adithyad?

Comment: @Labu Security group for API Gateway eh?